# Difference between NameError and SyntaxError

Tags: python, string, nameerror

I am aware that strings have to be surrounded by quotes (" ") for a variable to be defined or else a SyntaxError will occur.

Therefore, I am a little bit confused on what the difference is between a SyntaxError and NameError when it comes to variables not being defined.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is bonkers old but I'm writing this mainly for anyone else who (like myself from 5 minutes ago) may have this question, because call me crazy but "SyntaxError Raised when the parser encounters a syntax error" is not an answer that is going to make sense to anyone who needs to ask this question.

Its like answering "what is a potato?" with "a potato is the word you use to describe the object that is commonly known as a potato".

So, despite not being a a particularly knowledgeable programmer, let me try to explain what I've understood of it as best I can in a manner which may be more useful that "a syntax error is a syntax error".

Name error is the easier one to understand imo, its where you try to refer to a variable (/function? not sure abt that) which you have not defined yet. It is literally python saying "you have not yet named this thing, I can't do anything to it". Effectively its "this variable has not been initialized" (could happen therefore even when you mis-spell the variable name).

A syntax error is basically telling you you've got the grammar of the (python) language wrong. So if I write `for each chicken in chickens:` assuming chickens is a list of...well...chickens...its going to come back with a syntax error because python does not have that 'each' there. The correct grammar is `for chicken in chickens:`.

The reason python would raise such an error is because (this is my guess just based on assumption & logic, could be wrong), unlike say html (& maybe other languages do this) it is not going to assume what you meant. Its not going to say "well he probably meant this so let's just keep going forward under that assumption". (one reason for this would be to prevent infinite loops from occuring, for eg). BUT, it is smart enough to say "he probably meant this", its just cautious enough to go "oi, ya twit. If this is what you meant to write here, ya dun goofed".

Hope that a) I'm not wrong, and b) my explanation helps any future ppl.

Answer (score 0):

You could find all information [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

> *exception* **SyntaxError**
>   Raised when the parser encounters a syntax error. This may occur in an import statement, in an exec statement, in a call to the built-in function `eval()` or `input()`, or when reading the initial script or standard input (also interactively).
>   Instances of this class have attributes `filename`, `lineno`, `offset` and `text` for easier access to the details. `str()` of the exception instance returns only the message.
>
> *exception* **NameError**
>   Raised when a local or global name is not found. This applies only to unqualified names. The associated value is an error message that includes the name that could not be found.